# Is it possible and if so does it make sense to have dense layers in between LSTM layers?

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I am new to LSTMs and I was wondering if it is possible to have LSTM layer then dense then LSTM again and does it make sense?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE! Can you please provide a little bit more context? Why were you wondering about this? Are you asking whether this is theoretically possible or if this could be useful in some cases or has been used in some cases? Please, [edit your post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/posts/25905/edit) to include more details and address these questions. Please, take a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: I just know it's possible and you can easily implement it, but I don't know if it's good or not